# How to have bash script answer interactive prompts (no y/n only)?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker, environment-variables

I am trying to build a Docker image from a tool called [PHPCI](https://www.phptesting.org/). I was able to do almost everything but my first problem appears when I need to run a *setup* script for create database, setup usernames/password and do some kind of default configuration for the tool itself.

The script should be called as ([see here](https://www.phptesting.org/wiki/Installing-PHPCI) - Installing from Composer):

```
php ./console phpci:install
```

And it'll start asking for some questions. This is a full example of what is being asked:

```
******************
 Welcome to PHPCI
******************

Checking requirements... OK

Please answer the following questions:
-------------------------------------

Please enter your MySQL host [localhost]: 
Please enter your MySQL database name [phpci]:
Please enter your MySQL username [phpci]: 
Please enter your MySQL password:   
Your PHPCI URL ("http://phpci.local" for example): http://phpci.localdomain
Use beanstalkd to manage build queue? <yes|no>
Skipping beanstalkd configuration.
Setting up your database... OK
Admin Email: <email>
Admin Name: <user_name>
Admin Password:
User account created!
```

I am storing most of those parameters in `ENV` variables so I can read them easily after the container start. Or even better they can be `ARG`. My question is how I can make the install script to read the values from the `ENV` variables?

I know there is a lot of answers out there but most of them are for `yes|no` questions which seems to be easy but I couldn't find anything helpful regarding this one. Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Other than a heredoc or `expect`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams are you talking about [this](http://expect.sourceforge.net/)??

Comment: That would be the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these two test scripts:

```
tmp()
{
  var=fred
  tmp2 << EOD
$var
EOD
}

tmp2 ()
{
  read var2
  echo $var2
}
```

If you paste those into a shell, then run `tmp`, you'll get this:

```
> tmp
fred
```

The "heredoc" syntax lets you include responses to prompts in your script after the program.  So what you want to do is

```
php ./console phpci:install <<EOD
$HOST
$DATABASE
$USERNAME
$PASSWORD
[ ... etc ... ]
EOD
```

That should do it for you.  Note that you can include hard-coded values (instead of the variables) as well.

You can read more about [heredoc at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) if you like.

Hope this helps!